# Django get_model returns None for Mezzanine BlogPost model

Tags: python, django, django-models, mezzanine

I'm having a problem with `get_model` for Django. `get_model` works with every model I'm trying to get except for the `BlogPost` model from Mezzanine.

I've tried:

```
model = get_model('mezzanine.blog', 'BlogPost')
model = get_model('mezzanine', 'BlogPost')
```

Those lines return `None`. I have a feeling that I am not using the proper `app_label` for the first argument but I am not sure as to what the proper `app_label` is. Importing it normally works.

```
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost
```

I looked at the source code for Mezzanine and `BlogPost` is in the `mezzanine.blog` app so I assumed that the `app_label` should be `mezzanine.blog`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's `get_model` uses Django's app name + object name convention, where the app name is immediate package name, in this case `blog`. Try:

`model = get_model('blog', 'BlogPost')`